# Cannot find name 'MediaStreamTrackAudioSourceNode

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

so I updated my project to Angular 13 and now i get the following error while compiling the project:

node_modules/@ng-web-apis/audio/sources/media-stream-track-source.d.ts:3:61 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaStreamTrackAudioSourceNode'

any solution for this?

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.8
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.6.0
OS: win32 x64

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.8
@angular/cli                    13.3.8
@schematics/angular             13.3.8
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.6.4

"@ng-web-apis/audio": "^1.5.1",
```